# Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

[image: Structure of data;]

Using Python Pandas I am trying to find the `Country` & `Place` with the maximum value.

This returns the maximum value:

```
data.groupby(['Country','Place'])['Value'].max()
```

But how do I get the corresponding `Country` and `Place` name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find row where values for column is maximal in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Assuming `df` has a unique index, this gives the row with the maximum value:

```
In [34]: df.loc[df['Value'].idxmax()]
Out[34]: 
Country        US
Place      Kansas
Value         894
Name: 7
```

Note that [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns index *labels*. So if the DataFrame has duplicates in the index, the label may not uniquely identify the row, so `df.loc` may return more than one row.

Therefore, if `df` does not have a unique index, you must make the index unique before proceeding as above. Depending on the DataFrame, sometimes you can use `stack` or `set_index` to make the index unique. Or, you can simply reset the index (so the rows become renumbered, starting at 0):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Note this returns the *first* max row if there are multiple max values.

Comment: For future and others - note the words "Note that idxmax returns index *labels*."

Answer (score 122):

```
df[df['Value']==df['Value'].max()]
```

This will return the entire row with max value

Comment: Explanation :- The inner expression does a boolean check throughout the length of the dataFrame & that index which satisfies the right hand side of the expression( .max()) returns the index, which in turn calls the complete row of that dataFrame

Comment: Worth noting that this returns *all* rows if there are multiple same max values.

Answer (score 20):

I think the easiest way to return a row with the maximum value is by getting its index. `argmax()` can be used to return the index of the row with the largest value.

```
index = df.Value.argmax()
```

Now the index could be used to get the features for that particular row:

```
df.iloc[df.Value.argmax(), 0:2]
```

Answer (score 13):

The country and place is the index of the series, if you don't need the index, you can set `as_index=False`:

```
df.groupby(['country','place'], as_index=False)['value'].max()
```

Edit:

It seems that you want the place with max value for every country, following code will do what you want:

```
df.groupby("country").apply(lambda df:df.irow(df.value.argmax()))
```

Comment: that would only return the column names and the dtypes

Answer (score 9):

Use the `index` attribute of `DataFrame`. Note that I don't type all the rows in the example.

```
In [14]: df = data.groupby(['Country','Place'])['Value'].max()

In [15]: df.index
Out[15]: 
MultiIndex
[Spain  Manchester, UK     London    , US     Mchigan   ,        NewYork   ]

In [16]: df.index[0]
Out[16]: ('Spain', 'Manchester')

In [17]: df.index[1]
Out[17]: ('UK', 'London')
```

You can also get the value by that index:

```
In [21]: for index in df.index:
    print index, df[index]
   ....:      
('Spain', 'Manchester') 512
('UK', 'London') 778
('US', 'Mchigan') 854
('US', 'NewYork') 562
```

### Edit

Sorry for misunderstanding what you want, try followings:

```
In [52]: s=data.max()

In [53]: print '%s, %s, %s' % (s['Country'], s['Place'], s['Value'])
US, NewYork, 854
```

Comment: correct. But I'm looking for a one line output that says, 'US, Kansas, 894'

Comment: Thanks. This would solve the problem for the current dataset where there is just 1 column with values. When there are more columns with values @unutbu's solution would work better. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

In order to print the Country and Place with maximum value, use the following line of code.

```
print(df[['Country', 'Place']][df.Value == df.Value.max()])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
print(df[df['Value']==df['Value'].max()])
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Using [`DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html).

The dedicated method for this is `nlargest` which uses [`algorithm.SelectNFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f2c8480af2f25efdbd803218b9d87980f416563e/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L1263-L1277) on the background, which is a performant way of doing: `sort_values().head(n)`

```
   x  y  a  b
0  1  2  a  x
1  2  4  b  x
2  3  6  c  y
3  4  1  a  z
4  5  2  b  z
5  6  3  c  z
```

```
df.nlargest(1, 'y')

   x  y  a  b
2  3  6  c  y
```

Answer (score 3):

import pandas
df is the data frame you create.

Use the command:

```
df1=df[['Country','Place']][df.Value == df['Value'].max()]
```

This will display the country and place whose value is maximum.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for finding maximum values in columns:

```
df.ix[df.idxmax()]
```

, also minimum:

```
df.ix[df.idxmin()]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `nlargest` for better performance and shorter code. import `pandas`

```
df[col_name].value_counts().nlargest(n=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error while trying to import data using pandas, The first column on my dataset had spaces before the start of the words. I removed the spaces and it worked like a charm!!