# Pass the maximum value to x_range in Bokeh plot from a classifier feature importance

Tags: python, plot, graph, bokeh

Instead of setting x range manually in bokeh while plotting, I want to pass the maximum value of a column such as instead of setting max value to 10, it will be the max value of a certain column

```
p1 = figure(x_range=(0, 10))
```

**rf_important** is the feature importance of a classifier and is defined as

```
rf_important = pd.Series(new_rf.feature_importances_, index=x.columns)
```

Furthermore, rf is **pandas.core.series.Series**

I want to get the maximum value of the first column from rf_importance

```
rf.idmax
```

the above returns the maximum value in the feature importance rather than the maximum value in the columns. How can I access the columns and return the maximum value from there ?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You state that `rf` is a `Series`, and `rf.index` is a collection of column names. Then, `rf.index[0]` is just the name of the first column, of which you want the maximum. But where's the data for that column? In some `DataFrame`, perhaps?

Comment: @Eugene Pakhomov thanks for the tip I managed to find it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max(list) will return you the maximum value in a list.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(max(list))
```

Then you just need to pass it as the maximum value on to Bokeh.

Edit:
Maybe this helps: [Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan)

Comment: I think that assumes its a dataframe rather than a series

Comment: Yea, sorry I also do not know a lot about pandas. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the above variable 'rf' is type of **pandas.core.series.Series** therefore I could not access it using the max value directly. Also, 'rf' presented the **feature_importance** of a classifier rather than the values in the column that is why accessing it using the following code returned the letter rather the maximum value in the column

```
max(rf.index[0])
```

So to access the maximum value in the **feature_importance** of a classifer one most call the value from the original **DataFrame** using the **feature importance** as an index. such as

```
df[rf.index[0]].max()
```