# How can I select particular Columns in DataFrame based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an [IPL Data Set](https://www.kaggle.com/manasgarg/ipl) called `matches.csv` which I am fetching from Kaggle, from where I am trying to find out the place where the maximum number of matches were played.

The below code is giving me the correct value for the number of matches played, but I would like to check the Name of the Stadium where the maximum number of matches were played.

```
matches['venue'].value_counts().max()
```

This gives me 66

Expected Output is to be like:

```
M Chinnaswamy Stadium     66
```

Also if it is possible I would like to get all the details of the last match that was played in that Stadium.

Below is the head of the dataframe:

```
    id  season  city    date    team1   team2   toss_winner toss_decision   result  dl_applied  winner  win_by_runs win_by_wickets  player_of_match venue   umpire1 umpire2 umpire3
0   1   2017    Hyderabad   2017-04-05  Sunrisers Hyderabad Royal Challengers Bangalore Royal Challengers Bangalore field   normal  0   Sunrisers Hyderabad 35  0   Yuvraj Singh    Rajiv Gandhi International Stadium, Uppal   AY Dandekar NJ Llong    NaN
1   2   2017    Pune    2017-04-06  Mumbai Indians  Rising Pune Supergiant  Rising Pune Supergiant  field   normal  0   Rising Pune Supergiant  0   7   SPD Smith   Maharashtra Cricket Association Stadium A Nand Kishore  S Ravi  NaN
2   3   2017    Rajkot  2017-04-07  Gujarat Lions   Kolkata Knight Riders   Kolkata Knight Riders   field   normal  0   Kolkata Knight Riders   0   10  CA Lynn Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium  Nitin Menon CK Nandan   NaN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan)

Comment: @busybear, I dont think it's exactly a duplicate. Here he wants the max row from  `value_counts()`. Do you agree?

Comment: @najeem Yes, but the `value_counts` result is still a dataframe. Although I did just notice the last bit where OP asks for information from the _last_ match, which would require a bit more information as you pointed out.

Comment: @jezrael can we have this open now?

Comment: @anky_91 I cannot do it, only moderator. Vote for opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find out the place where the maximum number of matches were played**

```
>>matches['venue'].value_counts().head(1)
M Chinnaswamy Stadium    66
```

Note  that `value_counts` already sorts the data in a descending manner, so the first record is always the maximum.

**Get all the details of the last match that was played in that Stadium.**

```
>>matches[matches['venue']=='M Chinnaswamy Stadium'].sort_values('date',ascending=False).head(1)

    id  season  city    date    team1   team2   toss_winner toss_decision   result  dl_applied  winner  win_by_runs win_by_wickets  player_of_match venue   umpire1 umpire2 umpire3
57  58  2017    Bangalore   2017-05-19  Kolkata Knight Riders   Mumbai Indians  Mumbai Indians  field   normal  0   Mumbai Indians  0   6   KV Sharma   M Chinnaswamy Stadium   NJ Llong    Nitin Menon NaN
```

Here you can make a slice of the dataframe by querying the venue name, and then `sort_values` on the date column putting `ascending=False` and getting the first result, which gives you the latest match details.

**Note** I have used the latest kaggle dataset. The values might have changed, but the solution remains same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `value_counts()` to a new variable and then you can extract a subset of that data.

```
vmax = matches['venue'].value_counts()
vmax[vmax == vmax.max()]
```

> Also if it is possible I would like to get all the details of the last match that was played in that Stadium.

For this, you need to post sample of the dataset.