# Find next higher value in a python dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

we all now how to find the [maximum value of a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan).

But how can i find the next higher value in a column? So for example I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 4, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   col1  col2
0     3     3
1     5     4
2     2     3
```

**Basic-Questions:**
When I want to find the next higher value in `col1` to 0, outcome would be:`2`. Is there something similar to: `df.loc[df['col1'].idxmax()]`, which would lead to:

```
col1 col2
5    4
```

And my outcome should be:

```
col1 col2
2     3
```

***Background***: And I am using a if-condition to filter this dataframe, as I need to prepare it for further filtering, and not all values are exsting which I will put in:

```
v= 0
if len(df[(df['col1'] == v)]) == 0:
    df2 = df[(df['col1'] == v+1)]
else:
    df2 = df[(df['col1'] == v)]
```

This would lead to an empty dataframe.

But I would like to go the the next entry not `v+1=1` , in this case I want to insert `2`because it is the next higher value, which has entry after 0. So the condition would be:

```
v= 0
if len(df[(df['col1'] == v)]) == 0:
    df2 = df[(df['col1'] == 2)] #the 2 has to be find automatic, as the next value does not have a fixed distance
else:
    df2 = df[(df['col1'] == v)]
```

How can I achieve that automatically?

So my **desired outcome** is:

when I put in v=0:

```
df2
col1 col2
2     3
```

when I put in v=2, it jumps to v=3:

```
df2
col1 col2
 3     3
```

If I put v=3, it stays (else-condition):

```
df2
col1 col2
 3     3
```

Comment: So you want the 2nd highest value in a column? why is it the third entry and not the first because in col1 3 is bigger than 2

Comment: its the next highest value after a specific value, in my case i start with 0 , so it is 2

Comment: and v is the specific value?

Comment: yes, for v=3, the outcome would be row number 0, if you run my code. For v=2 it would be row number 0 as-well

Comment: What would happen if `v=3` or `v=5`?

Comment: then it goes in the else condition, and v=3: row0 from df, and v=5: row1

Comment: I think this might be an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) could you give some background on why you are filtering this way? There may be a better way to accomplish your end goal

Comment: your only question is basically how to set v automatic if the set is empty. is that correct? what if v = 4 would v be set to 3 or 5?

Comment: v=4, leads to 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `searchsorted` from `numpy`

```
df=df.sort_values('col1')
df.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.col1.values,[0])]
   col1  col2
2     2     3
df.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.col1.values,[3,5])]
   col1  col2
0     3     3
1     5     4
```

*Add-on(from the questioneer):* This also skips the if-condition

Comment: Nice one, does he always takes the next higher value?

Comment: @PV8 I think so and you can do a test on your side :-)

Comment: I checked it and can confirm it

Comment: @PV8 and `side='left'` we have this inside the function