# Python Return all Columns

Tags: python, pandas, max, row

i am a python newbie and got a probably simple question:
i want to get the highest 'Money' value and return it with its Name value.
Here is my Test Data Set:

```
        Name    Money
0   Serge   38.0    
1   Felix   31.5
2   Mike    17.0    
3   Alex    6.5     
4   Simon   29.5
```

So i want to get back `row[0].`
With
`max(df["Money"])`
i only get the Money value but not the name. How do i get the whole row?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df.nlargest(1, 'Money')`

Comment: or `df.loc[df['Money'].idxmax()]`

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564643/9081267)