# Get max value() of result of aggregate function by column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have this data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'country':['USA', 'China', 'Japan', 'Germany', 'UK', 'India', 'USA', 'India']
    ,'foo':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    ,'bar':[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With `df.groupby('country').agg(['count'])` I get the `count()`, `groupby` the `country`.

```
          GDP population
        count      count
country
China       1          1
Germany     1          1
India       2          2
Japan       1          1
UK          1          1
USA         2          2
```

How would I select the `row` with the `max()` value in the `column` `bar` or in the `column` `foo`? How to get the two `max()` (here India and USA) values back?

Comment: use idxmax to find the index?

Comment: @Stophface how do you want to handle degenerate max?

Comment: @Learningisamess What do you mean by that?

Comment: If more than one row has the max GDP, do you print one of them, or all of them, or else?

Comment: @Learningisamess All of them...

Comment: @Stophface I think your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# find the rows with a maximum either in foo or bar
mask = (counts == counts.values.max(0)).any(1)
res = counts[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        foo        bar
        count      count
country                 
India       2          2
USA         2          2
```

As suggested by @Stophface, instead of [.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas-dataframe-values), use [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) as recommended by the pandas documentation.

```
mask = (counts == counts.to_numpy().max(0)).any(1)
```

Comment: The Documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html states that `.to_numpy` is recommended over `.values`