# Selecting the row with the maximum value in a column in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I am using geopanda with python. I would like to select the row with the maximum value of column "pop".

I am trying the solution given here [Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan) :

```
city_join.loc[city_join['pop'].idxmax()]
```

However, it does not work. It says *"TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype"* . I think the reason is because that solution works for panda and not for geopandas. Am I right? How can I select the row with the maximun value of column "pop" in a geopanda dataframe?

Comment: Well what is the datatype? What does your data looks like?

Comment: It's an object. The solution of @ahmedshahriar works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your type with `print(df['columnName'].dtype)` and make sure it is numeric (i.e. integer, float ...). if it returns just object then use `df['columnName'].astype(float)` instead

Try with - `city_join.loc[city_join['pop'].astype(float).idxmax()]` if `pop` column is object type

Or

You can convert the column to numeric first

`city_join['pop'] = pd.to_numeric(city_join['pop'])`

and run your code `city_join.loc[city_join['pop'].idxmax()]`

Comment: It works. The problem was the 'pop' is an object. Thank you so much!