# pandas find the corresponding row value for the answer returned

Tags: python, pandas

For the below dataframe, `print data.groupby(['date'])['sales'].sum().max()` would return only the maximum value of total sales amongst the given days. How do I find out the date when the maximum sales occurred.

```
   date      brand   price    quantity      sales   vat
31-May-13   Reebok      10      23          230     3.5
31-May-13   Adidas      10      25          250     2.8
31-May-13   Campus      8       21          168     3.5
31-May-13   Nike        10      20          200     6.5
31-May-13   Woods       2       7           14      2.8
01-Jun-13   Reebok      4       27          108     2.2
01-Jun-13   Adidas      7       28          196     3.8
01-Jun-13   Campus      7       41          287     4.2
01-Jun-13   Nike        2       39          78      7.2
01-Jun-13   Woods       5       26          130     3.3
02-Jun-13   Reebok      10      5           50      2.2
02-Jun-13   Adidas      10      15          150     3.8
02-Jun-13   Campus      6       32          192     4.2
02-Jun-13   Nike        7       13          91      7.2
02-Jun-13   Woods       6       30          180     3.3
```

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213167/1889400)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.idxmax()` instead of `.max`

Definition: df.idxmax(self, axis=0, skipna=True)
Docstring:
Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.
NA/null values are excluded.

### Parameters

axis : {0, 1}
    0 for row-wise, 1 for column-wise
skipna : boolean, default True
    Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result
    will be first index.

### Returns

idxmax : Series

### Notes

This method is the DataFrame version of `ndarray.argmax`.

### See Also

Series.idxmax

```
In [19]: data.groupby(['date'])['sales'].sum().idxmax()
Out[19]: '31-May-13'
```