# Finding specific value in CSV file

Tags: python

So I have a function that finds the maximum value in a column in a csv file. I want to print the value thats on the same row as the max value, but in column 13. The code makes it clearer:

```
def bigQuake(inputfilename):

    file = open(inputfilename,"r")
    maxvalue = 0.0
    for line in file:
        value = line.split()
        try:
            p = float(line.split(",")[4])
            maxvalue = max(maxvalue,p)
        except:
            pass
return maxvalue
```

The code above simply finds the maxvalue of column 4, what's not working is when I replace

```
return maxvalue
```

with

```
print("The largest earthquake was a " + maxvalue + "magnitude earthquake" + value[12])
```

value[12] is trying to find the value in column 12 that corresponds to the max value of column 4. Note that column 12 contains strings, so I want the output to  look like this:

```
>>>bigQuake(file.csv)
>>>The largest earthquake was a 50 magnitude earthquake 10km from San Francisco.
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] this to correctly format your code? As it's written this doesn't even run. Also: what's your actual question? What's not working?

Comment: The `def bigQuake...` should be in the code block.

Comment: This looks trivial with the `pandas` library.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/pandas-dataframe-find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal ; You'd need to use `df = pandas.read_csv(fname) ` to get the data into a pandas data frame.

Comment: code fixed, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Track the value of magnitude corresponding to the maximum value in the 4th column.

Also better use [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from standard library for parsing csv files:

```
import csv

def bigQuake(inputfilename):
    with open(inputfilename,"r") as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)

        maxvalue = 0.0
        magnitude = None
        for line in reader:
            try:
                p = float(line[4])
                if p > maxvalue:
                    maxvalue = p
                    magnitude = line[12]
            except ValueError:
                pass

    print("The largest earthquake was a", maxvalue, "magnitude earthquake", magnitude, ".")
```

Also, note that you should use [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager while working with files and catch only [specific to situation exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-we-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-python).

Hope that helps.