# Parsing data with a loop on same name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Trying to do same parsing from csv file.

```
1  Xe   Xe   Xe   Xe   Xe    Zi   Zi   Zi   Zi    Zi
2  A    B    C    D    WOW   E    F    G    L    WOW
3
4
5                      data                     data2
6
```

trying to parse "data at index 5 and column WOW. So i tried

```
df = pd.read_csv("wow.csv", index_col=0, header=1)

data = df.loc[5, 'WOW']
```

it's actually working but just giving me data of first WOW not second or third...
how can I loop and take all WOW's data?

Answer (score 1):

Using `df.loc`

```
df.loc[5,df.loc[2]=='WOW']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd

file = 'a.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
for data in df.iterrows():
    print(data)
```

a.csv

```
Names,Highscore
Mel,8
Jack,5
David,3
Peter,6
Maria,5
Ryan,9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 95% certain that the data from your second and third WOW columns were lost as soon as you read them into your DataFrame.

[Pandas read_table with duplicate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207560/pandas-read-table-with-duplicate-names)

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9424

You'll have to find a different way to read in the file...

**EDIT**

People keep posting solutions for how to find the data when WOW is *part of the column data*, but the OP's code includes `header=1` in the `pd.read_csv`, so the problem is that WOW *becomes the column index*. You cannot have two columns with the same index. I'd comment this on the posts if only I had enough reputation points to do so...

**EDIT 2**

Okay, that was a brain cramp, between us we had the full answer: the solution to OP's problem is 1) get rid of `header=1` in the `pd.read_csv` call, i.e. get those WOWs out of the column header, and then 2) use the solution posted by @Wen-Ben, which will work once this modification is made.