# Pandas, select maximum from one column and minimum from another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
A         B
25        0.5
21        0.6
17        0.7
14        0.7   <--- this is the row I want
12        0.3
```

I'd like to select the maximum `B` with minimum `A`.

Is there a pandas easy trick to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame - Find row where values for column is maximal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/pandas-dataframe-find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal)

Comment: Typically I'd agree but I don't think that duplicate covers it

Comment: @jpp don't know, there's probably a duplicate somewhere in this site, given it's a really easy question, but it's not that one

Comment: @filippo - Dont worry, if question will be closed, let me or cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ know and question will be reopened. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare column `B` by `max` values and then get index of minimal `A` by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html), last select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['B'] == df['B'].max(), 'A'].idxmin()
print (a)
3

#for one row DataFrame use [[]]
df = df.loc[[a]]
print (df)
    A    B
3  14  0.7

#for Series use []
s = df.loc[a]
print (s)
A    14.0
B     0.7
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.loc[df['B'] == df['B'].max(), 'A'])

2    17
3    14
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, using `where` + `idxmin`:

```
df.iloc[df.where(df.B.eq(df.B.max())).A.idxmin()]

A    14.0
B     0.7
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```