# Pandas: groupby by one column, select rows with the (local) minimum value in one column and the (local) maximum in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with this structure:

```
                 sampleid  ploidy  purity     error
0              1962666_A1       2    0.05  0.330501
1              1962666_A1       2    0.09  0.337803
2              1962666_A1       2    0.97  0.991373
3              1962666_A1       3    0.05  0.283901
4              1962666_A1       3    0.10  0.331267
1233  1640057_030959B2_P5       5    0.11  0.359961
1234  1640057_030959B2_P5       5    0.13  0.395113
1235  1640057_030959B2_P5       5    0.19  0.408185
1236  1640057_030959B2_P5       5    0.34  0.437057
1237  1640057_030959B2_P5       5    1.00  0.523207
```

I need to identify, for each `sampleid` (hence, requiring a groupby) the row with the **largest** purity but with the lowest error. It doesn't necessarily mean the absolute lowest or maximum value, see below. In addition, I need to keep whatever value is in the `ploidy` column.

Given the above data as an example, for the first `sampleid` the fifth row satisfies the conditions: it has 0.10 in purity, and 0.331267 error (not 0.97, because the associated error is larger than the others).

Aside the fact that this requires `groupby`, I've tried with different approaches but no luck.

For example,

`df.groupby("sampleid").agg({"purity": "max", "error": "min"})`

Actually shuffles the columns around (example shown for another sample):

```
df.groupby("sampleid").agg({"purity": "max", "error": "min"}).loc["1962666_B2"]

purity    0.670000
error     0.680062
Name: 1962666_B2, dtype: float64

df.query("sampleid == '1962666_B2' and purity == 0.670000")

      sampleid  ploidy  purity     error
30  1962666_B2       5    0.67  0.988684
```

Other approaches I've tried involved using `scipy`'s `argrelextrema` but I could use only one condition at a time, which is incorrect (it will select either the rows with the lowest error but also the lowest purity, or the highest purity and the highest error).

I've looked through SO (e.g. [Pandas, select maximum from one column and minimum from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148539/pandas-select-maximum-from-one-column-and-minimum-from-another)) , but I didn't find a question that takes on this problem explicitly, most of the solutions are for one column only or they don't fit the exact problem.

What would the correct approach be here?

Comment: Until you make a key decision, your goal is inconsistent. You can't simply take the max of one variable and the min of another. You need to decide _priority_ or _weight_. If you follow a priority approach, you would e.g. sort on purity first and error second. If you follow a weight approach you would multiply each of those columns by a different weight by performing one matrix multiplication and the choosing the argmax of the ideal metric.

Comment: And if for the first sampleid the `purity = 0.10` would be associated to error `0.338888`, would you pick `purity=0.09  error=0.337803` in that case?

Comment: [here is your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSOC3.png), it looks like error increases with purity. There isn't one obvious answer, you might want to prioritize purity and except a higher error, or decrease error and accept a lower quality. We cannot make this choice for you, what would be the rules to decide?

Comment: @mozway The rule to decide is, the highest purity available while minimizing the error. The data arrives from a model which hands me a number of local minima (for errors). There will be some degree of manual intervention, this step is to exclude the obviously "incorrect" points.

Comment: I understand, but "obvious" is not the same for everyone. As I said in my answer, a good approach might be to combine several criteria. For instance, you might decide that all errors greater than 0.5 must be removed. Then you need to think of a logic. Do you really want to minimize error or to get the point with the most likely highest purity? For instance if you have purity 0.8 / error 0.1 and purity 0.5 / error 0.02, which one would you get? Of course the 0.1 error is much greater than 0.02 but 0.8±0.1 is almost certainly greater than 0.5±0.02. Can you give more details on the units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the error reflects the measurement of the purity, you could try to compute `purity*(1-error)` (or something similar) to correct the purity, and get the max corrected value with [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df.eval('purity*(1-error)').groupby(df['sampleid']).idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
                 sampleid  ploidy  purity     error
1237  1640057_030959B2_P5       5     1.0  0.523207
4              1962666_A1       3     0.1  0.331267
```

Purities (●) and corrected purities (◂):

[image]

How you correct the values in a meaningful way remains to be defined. You can combine several methods, for instance mask all values above a given threshold and correct the others.