# Grabbing the Highest value in Excel Column and display Row Name using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'm still fairly new to Python and Pandas and wanted to see if this was possible using pandas. I've read online that the best approach would be using idxmax.

What I'm trying to do:
Search through an excel file called 'Sample' - Check the 'Difference' column and find the highest value --> Grab the 'Metric' name and display into a notepad file/browser. Below, is a picture for reference.
[image]

Here is a small snippet that I have seen online, any assistance on how to do this would be appreciated.

Code:

```
metric_column = Metric[:,1].astype(int)
metric = metric_column[np.argmax(Difference)]
```

Comment: how are you loading your excel into pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame - Find row where values for column is maximal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/pandas-dataframe-find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal)

Comment: I'm using df = pandas.read_excel & also @Yuca, I don't see that tutorial including anything using Excel.

Comment: ok, so my answers is based on the assumption that the metric column is at position 0, it should work!

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will be trying your method.

Comment: did it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
df.iloc[df['Difference'].idxmax(), 0]
```

Comment: please consider to accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left side of the answer :)