# Problem with group by max period in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still a novice with python and I'm having problems trying to group some data to show that record that has the highest (maximum) date, the dataframe is as follows:

[image]
...
[image]

I am trying the following:

```
df_2 = df.max(axis = 0) 
df_2 = df.periodo.max()
df_2 = df.loc[df.groupby('periodo').periodo.idxmax()]
```

And it gives me back:

```
Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00')

periodo    2020-06-01 00:00:00
valor                  3.49136
```

Although the value for 'periodo' is correct, for 'valor' it is not, since I need to obtain the corresponding complete record ('period' and 'value'), and not the maximum of each one. I have tried other ways but I can't get to what I want ...

I need to do?

Thank you in advance, I will be attentive to your answers!

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# import packages we need, seed random number generator
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
random.seed(1)
```

---

### Create example dataframe

```
dates = [single_date for single_date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(day_count))]
values = [random.randint(1,1000) for _ in dates]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates,values),columns=['dates','values'])
```

ie `df` will be:

```
    dates    values
0   2020-01-01  389
1   2020-01-02  808
2   2020-01-03  215
3   2020-01-04  97
4   2020-01-05  500
5   2020-01-06  30
6   2020-01-07  915
7   2020-01-08  856
8   2020-01-09  400
9   2020-01-10  444
```

---

### Select rows with highest entry in each column

You can do:

```
df[df['dates'] == df['dates'].max()]
```

(Or, if wanna use `idxmax`, can do: `df.loc[[df['dates'].idxmax()]]`)

Returning:

```
    dates   values
9   2020-01-10  444
```

*ie this is the row with the latest date*

&

```
df[df['values'] == df['values'].max()]
```

(Or, if wanna use `idxmax` again, can do: `df.loc[[df['values'].idxmax()]]` - as in [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206701/8565438).)

and

```
    dates   values
6   2020-01-07  915
```

*ie this is the row with the highest value in the `values` column*.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: hello !, thank you very much for your help and your time !!, indeed it is as you say :) well !!, I will keep it in mind for the future, thank you very much for your help !! Greetings ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like:

```
df.loc[[df['valor'].idxmax()]]
```

Where you use `idxmax` on the 'valor' column.  Then use that index to select that row.

MVCE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'periodo':pd.date_range('2018-07-01', periods = 600, freq='d'), 
                  'valor':np.random.random(600)+3})

df.loc[[df['valor'].idxmax()]]
```

Output:

```
       periodo     valor
474 2019-10-18  3.998918
```

Comment: Super!! Thank you very much for your explanation, now I have it clearer !! thanks for your help and time I appreciate it :) regards !!