# Get max value from dataframe with other information

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe from which I need to extract max value. Here is the example of DF:

| Object | PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Param1 | 1 |
| B | Param2 | 3 |
| C | Param1 | 5 |
| D | Param1 | 2 |
| E | Param3 | 4 |

Get max value:

```
maxval = data['VALUE'][data['PARAMETER'] == 'Param1'].max()
print(maxval)    #  5
```

This works fine but I would like to also get Object name of extracted max value, so the output should be like:

> Object name: C, max value = 5

How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find row where values for column is maximal in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax()` it will give you the index for maximum value.

```
index = data['VALUE'][data['PARAMETER'] == 'Param1'].idxmax()
```

Now you can use this index to get any  columns or the entire row.

```
data.loc[index, 'Object']
```

**Sample Run:**

```
>>import pandas as pd
>>df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': ['A', 'B','C','D', 'E'], 'PARAMETER': ['Param1', 'Param2', 'Param3', 'Param2', 'Param1'], 'VALUE':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
>>df
  Object PARAMETER  VALUE
0      A    Param1      1
1      B    Param2      2
2      C    Param3      3
3      D    Param2      4
4      E    Param1      5
```

**OUTPUT:**
The masking:

```
>>df[df['PARAMETER'] == 'Param1']
  Object PARAMETER  VALUE
0      A    Param1      1
4      E    Param1      5
```

The `idxmax()`:

```
>>df[df['PARAMETER'] == 'Param1']['VALUE'].idxmax()
4
```

From the masking, as you can notice, maximum index is 4, that's what `idxmax()` yields. Now you can use this index to access any column like this:

```
>>index = df['VALUE'][df['PARAMETER'] == 'Param1'].idxmax()
>>df.loc[index, 'Object']
'E'
```

or the entire row:

```
    >>df.loc[index]
    Object            E
    PARAMETER    Param1
    VALUE             5

Name: 4, dtype: object
```

Comment: I get exception TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype. Could be this because Values in my test also can contain floating point values?

Comment: You need to use single column in order to use idxmax(), I have added more details to the answer, you can check