# How do i pick a specific item in a row that has the same corresponding value with the column list - Pandas Pyhton

Tags: python, pandas

*I have just started programming, pardon in any misuse of terms. Thanks for the help in advance. English is not my first language, thank you for understanding*.
I am using Pandas in Pyhton.
I have created a datalist using `df = pd.read_csv` from a csv file.This is what the CSV file contains

```
Year,A,B,C,D,E,F
2007,7632014,4643033,206207,626668,89715,18654926
2008,6718487,4220161,379049,735494,58535,29677697
2009,1226858,5682198,482776,1015181,138083,22712088
2010,978925,2229315,565625,1260765,146791,15219378
2011,1500621,2452712,675770,1325025,244073,19697549
2012,308064,2346778,591180,1483543,378998,33030888
2013,275019,4274425,707344,1664747,296136,17503798
2014,226634,3124281,891466,1807172,443671,16023363
2015,2171559,3474825,1144862,1858838,585733,16778858
2016,767713,4646350,2616322,1942102,458543,13970498
2017,759016,4918320,1659303,2001220,796343,9730659
2018,687308,6057191,1524474,2127583,1224471,19570540
```

I know how to select a specific row/column in the dataframe using:

```
data_2012 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[6])
data_A = (df.loc[5:12, 0:10][1].values.tolist())
```

I need to find max, min values in the column list `data_A` so I have created

```
maximum_A = max(data_A)
minimum_A = min(data_A)
```

I also have created a list for all the needed rows

```
data_2011 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[5])
data_2012 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[6])
data_2013 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[7])
data_2014 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[8])
data_2015 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[9])
data_2016 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[10])
data_2017 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[11])
data_2018 = (df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[12])
```

I tried to make them into a single list as shown

```
data_allyears = (data_2011, data_2012, data_2013, data_2014, data_2015, data_2016, data_2017, data_2018)
```

The issue is, how do I select an item from that particular row that has the value from the min,max value. Let's say the max value is in the year 2012, how do I automatically print the year itself where the max value is. I have tried this but nothing happened:

```
for a,b,c in zip(maximum_A, minimum_A, data_allyears):
    if a == c:
        print(f"${a} in year {c}")
```

Comment: `(df.loc[0:12, 1:7].values.tolist()[7])` <- this doesn't work, you have to use `iloc` instead `loc`?

Comment: I'm not sure I have read the question right, but if I have, this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202570/find-row-where-values-for-column-is-maximal-in-a-pandas-dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

Try this ; lets call your dataframe `df` :

```
df.loc[df.Year == df.Year.max()]
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I automatically print the year itself where the max value is

```
# get year of maximum of A
column = 'A'
year = df.loc[df[column] == max(df[column]), ['Year']].values[0][0]
print(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `Year` as index and find max value for each year

```
df1 = df.set_index('Year').assign(Min=lambda x: x.max(axis=1),
                                  Max=lambda x: x.min(axis=1))
print(df1)

# Output
            A        B        C        D        E         F       Min     Max
Year                                                                         
2007  7632014  4643033   206207   626668    89715  18654926  18654926   89715
2008  6718487  4220161   379049   735494    58535  29677697  29677697   58535
2009  1226858  5682198   482776  1015181   138083  22712088  22712088  138083
2010   978925  2229315   565625  1260765   146791  15219378  15219378  146791
2011  1500621  2452712   675770  1325025   244073  19697549  19697549  244073
2012   308064  2346778   591180  1483543   378998  33030888  33030888  308064
2013   275019  4274425   707344  1664747   296136  17503798  17503798  275019
2014   226634  3124281   891466  1807172   443671  16023363  16023363  226634
2015  2171559  3474825  1144862  1858838   585733  16778858  16778858  585733
2016   767713  4646350  2616322  1942102   458543  13970498  13970498  458543
2017   759016  4918320  1659303  2001220   796343   9730659   9730659  759016
2018   687308  6057191  1524474  2127583  1224471  19570540  19570540  687308
```

Comment: Does it solve your answer?